# Generate permutation of a sparse vector

Tags: algorithm, permutation

Say I am trying to generate a permutation of `[21 2 0 34 0 0 0 1]` that would move all of the zeros at the end (keep in mind that the number of zeros could be big, think of this as a sparse vector) of the vector and the non-zero values would be shifted in the front of the vector, without changing their natural order. The result would be `[21 2 34 1 0 0 0 0 ]`. What's a solution that's computationally efficient for large vectors of this kind:

1. Go over the vector and add to another vector the non-zero elements and then fill the rest of the 2nd vector with zeros?
2. Generate all permutations for the given vector (they're roughly `n!/m!` where `n` is the length of the vector and `m` is the number of zeros, if we disregard the number of non-zero elements that could appear more than once) and pick the combinations that fits this restriction.

Comment: You forgot bogosort as option 3. Seriously, it's never computationally efficient to create all permutations of something, even if you think that n - m is small.

Answer (score 4):

Simply iterate over the vector and compare every item to zero. If it is zero, remember its index. If it isn't zero and you're remembering the index of an empty field, move it there and change your remembered index. Takes linear time and requires only one cell of additional storage. I can't think of any more efficient way to do this.

Comment: Notice that in a sparse vector will exist consecutive zeros, so a simple cell to keep the zero index is not enough. You will need a vector for holding the zero indexes.

Comment: No, once you have moved an item to the first zero cell, you know where the next zero cell is without looking. Try it out with some board game figures...

Answer (score 1):

The most effective solution is to iterate over the vector and move all non-zero numbers in front of the zeros. This algorithm is analogous to [stable_partition](http://cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/stable_partition/) algorithm of STL with pred equals to 'elem != 0'.

But if you need to keep the original vector, your first idea seems to be the optimal one. Just to be clear, in this case you should allocate the memory for the whole vector before processing and consequentially fill its elements, instead of adding new elements to the end of the vector on each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

From your suggested solutions obviously the first one is faster, because it runs **O(n)** in opposite to **O(n!)** run time of the second one. I can suggest a bit improvement to it in order to avoid external memory usage:

Keep two pointers: `i` which points to the first zero position, and `j` that just iterates over the vector. At each step, if `v[ j ] != 0` put its value to `i`-th position and increase `i`. Hereby you will do without additional memory. Also in such way you will perform exactly **N + non_zero_elements_qty** iterations, while in your solution 1 iterations quantity is **N + zero_elements_qty**, which is still **O(n)**, but can be slower if the vector is rather sparse.

Here is a possible implementation in C++:

```c++
// input vector<int> v
int n = v.size();
int i = 0;
while( v[ i ] != 0 ) ++i;
for( int j = 0; j < n; ++j )
   if( v[ j ] != 0 )
      v[ i++ ] = v[ j ];
```